# Custom post type - order field

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, order

In a custom post type, is there a way to include the "order" field that is available for pages?

Is there any built-in logic that prevents duplicate values in the "order" field?

The idea is to be able to sort a custom post type by a user-specified order, then alphabetically by a string-based custom field.

Comment: Duplicate: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43970/adding-menu-order-column-to-custom-post-type-admin-screen

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When declaring your custom post type using the register_post_type function, you have to add 'page-attributes' to the support field, like in the following example:

```
register_post_type('myposttype', array(
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'page-attributes'),
    'hierarchical' => false
));
```

You'll need to add any other supported meta boxes as well to the 'supports' field, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/ for more information about the register_post_type fields.

Also as far as I know there isn't any built in way to prevent two of the same order, this is because you can create sub-ordering based on heirarchy (so one group of children pages can have a different ordering than another)

Comment: using `page-attributes` presents both the `order` field and the `parent` field. How do I get rid of the `parent` field?

Comment: Nevermind. Setting `hierarchical` to false gets rid of it.

Comment: My bad, didn't realize you didn't also want the page parents. I'll update my answer to exclude it.

Comment: Hi. I have this code but I see nothing:

```

// Service Custom Post Type
 add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
 function create_post_type() {

   $supports_args = array(
     'title', 'editor', 'page-attributes'
   );
   register_post_type( 'service',
     array(
       'labels' => array(
         'name' => __( 'Services' ),
         'singular_name' => __( 'Service' ),
         'supports' => $supports_args,
         'hierarchical' => false
       ),
       'public' => true,
       'has_archive' => true,
       //'menu_position' => 2
     )
   );
 }

```

Comment: @Sylar I realize this is very late, but it looks to me like your 'supports' => $supports_args, 'hierarchical' => false is in the wrong part of the array. You have it nested under the labels array in your example, it should be in the base array, at the same level as 'public' => true

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Dave-Hunt's response, you can also add a filter, such as the following, to define a custom order - in this case, alphabetical by title. (Code thanks to [Mark Leong's blog post.](http://www.mark-leong.com/set-wordpress-custom-post-types-order-in-admin/)) Remove the `is_admin()` check, if you want you custom order_by on the front-end as well.

```
function set_custom_post_types_admin_order($wp_query) {
  if (is_admin()) {

    // Get the post type from the query
    $post_type = $wp_query->query['post_type'];

    if ( $post_type == 'POST_TYPE') {

      // 'orderby' value can be any column name
      $wp_query->set('orderby', 'title');

      // 'order' value can be ASC or DESC
      $wp_query->set('order', 'ASC');
    }
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'set_custom_post_types_admin_order');
```

**Update**

For pre-save validation, see this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/40095/4645
where your options are discussed.  Basically, it comes down to custom jQuery, as WordPress doesn't have any pre-save hooks.

Also (duplicating my previous comment here for future reference), here's how to expose the 'menu order' field in the admin, so it's user-editable, as it is for pages: [Adding 'menu order' column to custom post type admin screen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/43970/4645)