# Slider from custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, slideshow

I am making one custom slider where admin can add slider image from back end. I am doing it with the help of custom post type.

`function.php`

```
// Custom Post types for Feature project on home page 
   add_action('init', 'create_feature');
     function create_feature() {
       $feature_args = array(
          'labels' => array(
           'name' => __( 'Feature Project' ),
           'singular_name' => __( 'Feature Project' ),
           'add_new' => __( 'Add New Feature Project' ),
           'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Feature Project' ),
           'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Feature Project' ),
           'new_item' => __( 'Add New Feature Project' ),
           'view_item' => __( 'View Feature Project' ),
           'search_items' => __( 'Search Feature Project' ),
           'not_found' => __( 'No feature project found' ),
           'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No feature project found in trash' )
         ),
       'public' => true,
       'show_ui' => true,
       'capability_type' => 'post',
       'hierarchical' => false,
       'rewrite' => true,
       'menu_position' => 20,
       'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
     );
  register_post_type('feature',$feature_args);
}
add_filter("manage_feature_edit_columns", "feature_edit_columns");

function feature_edit_columns($feature_columns){
   $feature_columns = array(
      "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
      "id" => "ID",
      "title" => "Title",
   );
  return $feature_columns;
}



add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add' );
function cd_meta_box_add()
{
    add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', 'Link to Project', 'cd_meta_box_cb', 'feature', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function cd_meta_box_cb( $post )
{
    $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'url', true);
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' ); ?>

    <p>
        <label for="url">Project url</label>
        <input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="<?php echo $url; ?>" style="width:350px" />
    </p>

    <?php   
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_box_save' );
function cd_meta_box_save( $post_id )
{
    // Bail if we're doing an auto save
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    // if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

    // if our current user can't edit this post, bail
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    // now we can actually save the data
    $allowed = array( 
        'a' => array( // on allow a tags
            'href' => array() // and those anchors can only have href attribute
        )
    );

    // Probably a good idea to make sure your data is set
    if( isset( $_POST['url'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'url', wp_kses( $_POST['url'], $allowed ) );
}
```

After above code, I get  output like 
[image]

Here I want something like `ID` after `Title`. So that admin can be able to set slide Image order from that `ID`.

Can anyone tell me how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the purpose of the ID is just to set the order of the slides you are better off using the order attribute.

Add `page-attributes` to the array for the `supports` argument in `$feature_args`
Then in your loop you can specify `&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC`

Then you can show it as a column you can refer to this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43970/adding-menu-order-column-to-custom-post-type-admin-screen)

Answer (score 0):

Hre is the code for adding ID column in feature post type.

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-feature_columns', 'set_custom_edit_feature_columns' );
add_action( 'manage_feature_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_feature_column', 10, 2 );

function set_custom_edit_feature_columns($columns) {
    unset( $columns['date'] );
    $columns['ID'] = __( 'ID', 'twentyfourteen' );
    return $columns;
}

function custom_feature_column( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'ID' :
        echo $post_id;
        break;
    }
}
```